# My app not uploading and running on emulator issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development and trying to develop an android food ordering app for my class project. I have no coding background and am developing the app using Youtube and Udacity's Android app development course. However, whenever I try to see the progress of my app in the android emulator I run into some form of error that doesn't allow me to see how my app looks like on the emulator. The latest problem that I am facing is

```
com.google.android.instantapps.sdk.lib.AdbHelper$AdbCommandException: ADB 
command timed out: [shell, pm dump com.example.broncogrill]
Command output:

Error while Uploading and launching Instant App
```

I am not able to understand Why this issue is there. Is there something wrong with my code or is there some other issue with the Emulator that is not allowing me to upload and launch the app?

I have tried disabling instant run but that didn't work. Then I tried increasing the connection time out from 5,000 milliseconds to 50,000 milliseconds.

```java
 package com.example.broncogrill;

 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 import 
 com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
 import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
 TextView txtSlogan;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
     btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

     txtSlogan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
     Typeface face = 
     Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/NABILA.TTF");
     txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);

     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
     });

     btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
     });

     Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
     fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
                     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .setAction("Action", null).show();
         }
     });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     int id = item.getItemId();

     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
     }

     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 }
```

`build.gradle`

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.broncogrill"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0- 
    alpha4'

    // Add Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I just want to solve this issue and get the app to run on the emulator so that I can transfer it to my phone and do the demo in my class

Comment: Please if someone can give me some solution to get this to work it will be great. That way i can continue working on the app